# Is it posible to choose a SIM card while making a call through Cortana

Tags: 8.1, cortana, calls, dual-sim

I use Cortana a lot to make calls. However every time I call a person using Cortana it seems to call from the SIM through which the previous call was made. I would like to choose a SIM while making the call. Some voice commands I tried are

> Call Dad using SIM1
>
> Call Dad on SIM1
>
> Call Dad via SIM1
>
> Call Dad using/on/via first SIM
>
> Call Dad using BSNL mobile (the name of my SIM)

Is there any command that will make Cortana place a call on the SIM I choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently that feature is not available for Cortana, since currently Microsoft doesn't program Cortana to be able to make calls from a specific SIM card, but this is really a good feature to have since there are quite a large number of Windows Phones that have the dual SIM capability.

I recommend that you give this suggestion via Windows Feedback app in Windows 10 or Windows 10 Mobile. I'm sure to vote that up too, since that would be useful.

Comment: Provided feedback as you said.

Comment: Nice, I will vote up that feedback if I came across it.